# CSS Color Code to Add In HTML Header Logo,Nav same Line Block

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I can't figure out how to adjust the color of this Block , what i want is black color so it would follow what the original background own.

Here is what the codes look like, : `https://codepen.io/dewajoker/pen/LYxmeVB`

What i mean is like this screnshot. How to adjust the nav button color to be the same as background color, only for mobile site

```
  the site is : https://dewagacor.com/
```

Have someone correct me and tell me how to fix ? will be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Read this section of docs on bootstrap
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#color-schemes

try using the other color scheme provided by adding the relevant class to your navbar using the `.navbar-dark` for dark background colors

You can customise the navbar using the `.bg-* utilities`

To get a dark theme navbar when using bootstrap do this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>
```